# Test an inner class exists with RSpec and PDK

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet, pdk

I have a fairly basic puppet module for a webservice running tomcat. I want to setup logrotate on Tomcat's `catalina.out` file, and I want to start by writing a test that confirms logrotate is included in the module and setup with the correct settings.

Here's a stripped down version of my `webservice.pp`, for example:

```rb
class my_module::webservice (
  ...
){
  include ::tomcat_server

  ...

  logrotate::rule { 'tomcat':
    path          => '/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out',
    rotate        => 1,
    rotate_every  => 'day',
    copytruncate  => true,
    missingok     => true,
    compress      => true,
    delaycompress => true,
  }
}
```

and I have included the logrotate forge module in my `.fixtures.yml` like so:

```rb
fixtures:
  forge_modules:
    logrotate:
      repo: 'puppet-logrotate'
      ref:  '3.2.1'
    ...
```

But I can only write a test that confirms that `logrotate` is included in the module like so:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'my_module::webservice' do
  on_supported_os.each do |os, os_facts|
    context "on #{os}" do
      let(:facts) { os_facts }

      it { is_expected.to compile }

      it { is_expected.to contain_class('logrotate') }
    end
  end
end
```

This doesn't work (if I remove the logrotate block from `init.pp` then the tests still pass):

```rb
it { is_expected.to contain_class('logrotate::conf') }
```

nor does asking for `with`:

```rb
it { is_expected.to contain_class('logrotate') \
  .with('path'          => '/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out',
        'rotate'        => 1,
        'rotate_every'  => 'day',
        'copytruncate'  => true,
        'missingok'     => true,
        'compress'      => true,
        'delaycompress' => true,
  )
}
```

and nor does a separate/nested `describe` block:

```rb
describe 'logrotate::rule' do
  let(:title) { 'tomcat' }
  let(:params) do
    {
        'path'          => '/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out',
        'rotate'        => 1,
        'rotate_every'  => 'day',
        'copytruncate'  => true,
        'missingok'     => true,
        'compress'      => true,
        'delaycompress' => true,
    }
  end
end
```

I can't find anything in the rspec docs that mention anything other than testing the class is defined. Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do?

Here is my directory layout:

```
puppet
  `- modules
        `- my_module
             |- data
             |- manifests
             |    |- init.pp
             |    `- webservice.pp
             |- spec
             |    |- classes
             |    |    `- webservice_spec.rb
             |    `- spec_helper.rb
             |- .fixtures.yml
             |- Gemfile
             |- hiera.yaml
             |- metadata.json
             `- Rakefile
```

Comment: This sounds like a code organization/layout and/or RSpec/PDK usage issue if your tests pass regardless of code content. What does your layout look like and how are you using PDK?

Comment: I've updated the description with the directory layout. I'm using PDK by running `pdk test unit` in the `puppet/modules/my_module` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a fairly basic puppet module for a webservice running tomcat. I want to setup logrotate on Tomcat's catalina.out file, and I want to start by writing a test that confirms logrotate is included in the module and setup with the correct settings.

That sounds very reasonable.  However, this ...

> Here's a stripped down version of my init.pp, for example:
>
> ```
> class my_module::webservice (
>   ...
> ){
> ```

... is at best poor practice.  If it exists at all then the `init.pp` manifest of module `my_module` should define only class `my_module`.  A class named `my_module::webservice` should instead be defined in a manifest named `webservice.pp` in module `my_module`.  The expectations for module layout are [documented](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/modules_fundamentals.html#manifests) in the Puppet online documentation.  Although you might be able to get away with certain discrepancies from those specifications, there is only downside to doing so.

At this point I observe that "inner class" is not idiomatic Puppet terminology, and  it suggests a misunderstanding of what you're working with.  Specifically, this ...

> ```
> logrotate::rule { 'tomcat':
> ```
>
> [...]

... does not declare a *class* at all, but rather declares a *resource* of type `logrotate::rule`, which is apparently a defined type provided by the puppet/logrotate module.  In general, declaring a resource does not imply anything about classes from the module (if any) that provides the resource's type.

Furthermore, although it is entirely possible that declaring a `logrotate::rule` resource does cause class `logrotate` to be included in the catalog too, that would be an implementation detail of `logrotate::rule`, and as such, your spec tests should not be testing for it.  Only if `my_module::webservice` is expected to itself declare class `logrotate` should its tests be checking for that.

You go on to say:

> This doesn't work (if I remove the logrotate block from init.pp then
>   the tests still pass):
>
> ```
> it { is_expected.to contain_class('logrotate::conf') }
> ```

You haven't presented enough code for us to determine why the tests pass when that is included in them, but something is very strange if ever that expectation is satisfied. `logrotate::conf` is also a defined (resource) type, not a class, so that expectation should *never* succeed.  And following a theme I introduced above, if class `my_module::webservice` does not declare any `logrotate::conf` resource directly then its tests should not be checking for one.

> nor does asking for with:
>
> ```
> it { is_expected.to contain_class('logrotate') \
>   .with('path'          => '/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out',
>         'rotate'        => 1,
>         'rotate_every'  => 'day',
>         'copytruncate'  => true,
>         'missingok'     => true,
>         'compress'      => true,
>         'delaycompress' => true,
>   )
> }
> ```

Of course that doesn't succeed.  It expresses an expectation of a declaration of class `logrotate`, but what you've actually declared is a resource of type `logrotate::rule`.  Even if `logrotate::rule` did declare `logrotate`, one would not expect it to pass on its own parameter list.

> and nor does a separate/nested describe block:
>
> ```
> describe 'logrotate::rule' do
> ```
>
> [...]

Again, that's not surprising. Such a `describe` block tells RSpec that `logrotate::rule` is the class under test.  Not only is it not the class under test (that is of course `my_module::webservice`), but, again, `logrotate::rule` is not a class at all.  RSpec can certainly test defined types, too, but that's not what you're after here.

**To test whether a resource is declared by the class under test**, one uses a predicate of the form `contain_`*type*`(`*title*`)`, where any namespace separators (`::`) in the type name are replaced by double underscores.  For example:

```
it do
  is_expected.to contain_logrotate__rule('tomcat')
end
```

It is permitted, but optional, to include one or more `with` clauses to specify expectations of the declared parameters of the designated resource.  Following what you appear to have been trying to do, then, maybe this would more fully express what you're looking for:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'my_module::webservice' do
  on_supported_os.each do |os, os_facts|
    context "on #{os}" do
      let(:facts) { os_facts }

      it do
        is_expected.to compile
        is_expected.to contain_logrotate__rule('tomcat')
          .with(
            path: '/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out',
            rotate: 1,
            rotate_every: 'day',
            copytruncate: true,
            missingok: true,
            compress: true,
            delaycompress: true
          )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Do note, by the way, that when you want to test multiple predicates against the same example, it is substantially more efficient to group them together in the same `it` block, as demonstrated above, than to put each in its own `it` block.  As in, you will probably notice the difference in test running time even from combining just two `it` blocks into one.

Additionally, my example above demonstrates coding style close to that required to avoid warnings from `pdk validate`, which brings us to an additional point: it is always useful to verify that `pdk validate` completes without errors or warnings before trying the unit tests.  You will probably find that it is excessively picky about both Puppet and Ruby code style, but it will also pick up some issues that lead to mysterious test failures.  Also, it runs much faster than the tests do, and it will pick up substantially all syntax errors in both Puppet and Ruby code.  It's frustrating to have your tests take a long time to fail on account of a minor syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I only dip into ruby now and then and we have a lot of untested legacy code that I was hoping to improve with unit tests. I was definitely missing knowledge that what I was trying to add was a resource, and not a class.

I made a mistake with the `.pp` name -- my module isn't actually called `my_module` and I wanted to abstract sensitive information from the question at hand.

Comment: @Frangipanes, I understood that the module name is not actually `my_module`.  You can, of course, substitute the actual module name everywhere in this answer without affecting its meaning.  In particular, if the class under test is instead `some_other_name::webservice` then its definition still does not belong in its module's `init.pp` manifest.

Comment: With my `webservice_spec.rb` file updated to match what you have there, I get a test failure:

`expected that the catalogue would contain Logrotate_rule[tomcat]`

Comment: Sorry, @Frangipanes, I wrote a bit from memory, and am presently away from my Puppet infrastructure.  Instead of replacing the `::` with a single underscore, you replace it with two (that is, each colon gets converted to its own underscore).  [The RSpec::Puppet docs](https://rspec-puppet.com/documentation/classes/#test-a-resource) cover this.  I've updated the answer.